# Obtain a native method instance that binds a built-in function

Tags: python, cpython

A [partially documented](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#:%7E:text=Instance%20methods) behavior of Python's data model is that `__getattribute__` does not bind "built-in" functions:

```py
import logging, numpy
class TestBind:
    nobind = print
    nobind2 = numpy.array
    binds = logging.error
    def binds2(self): pass

print(TestBind.nobind)
print(TestBind.nobind2)
print(TestBind.binds)
print(TestBind.binds2)
# <built-in function print>
# <built-in function array>
# <function error at 0x1feedbeed>
# <function TestBind.binds2 at 0x1feedbeef>

t = TestBind()

print(t.nobind)
print(t.nobind2)
print(t.binds)
print(t.binds2)
# <built-in function print>
# <built-in function array>
# <bound method error of <__main__.TestBind object at 0x1beefcafe>>
# <bound method TestBind.binds2 of <__main__.TestBind object at 0x1beefcafe>>

print(type(t.binds))
# method
```

There is no built-in "instancemethod" descriptor equivalent to `classmethod`/`staticmethod`.  One can be defined, for example,

```py
from functools import partial
class instancemethod: 
    __slots__ = '_func',
    def __init__(self, func): 
        self._func = func 
    def __get__(self, inst, cls): 
        return self._func if inst is None else partial(self._func, inst)

class TestBind:
    ibinds = instancemethod(logging.error)
    ...
```

But naturally the results aren't `method` objects, and lack the properties of bound methods:

```py
print(t.ibinds)
# functools.partial(<function error at 0x1feedbeed>, <__main__.TestBind object at 0x1051af310>)
t.ibinds.__self__  # AttributeError
t.ibinds.__name__  # AttributeError
t.ibinds.__func__  # AttributeError
t.ibinds.__doc__  # wrong doc
```

Is it possible to write some `instancemethod` descriptor (or anything else) that produces bound `method` instances for C-defined functions?

#### Resolution:

Per Monica's answer below I used

```py
from types import MethodType

class instancemethod:
    """
    Convert a function to be an instance method.
    """
    __slots__ = '_func',
    def __init__(self, func):
        self._func = func
    def __get__(self, inst, owner=None):
        return self._func if inst is None else MethodType(self._func, inst)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I see the point in doing this, rather than just wrapping the function in a regular user-defined function to serve as the instance method. `function.__get__` returns a bound method because you can define the instance of `function` with your class in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct a method object directly with `types.MethodType`:

```
import types

class instancemethod:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        if instance is None:
            return self.func
        return types.MethodType(self.func, instance)
```

Note that the signature of `types.MethodType` is subject to change. It used to be different back in Python 2, when unbound method objects still existed.